# how to extract properly when sqlite json has value as an array

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I have a sqlite database and in one of the fields I have stored complete json  object . I have to make some json select requests . If you see my json 
the ALL key has value which is an array . **We need to extract some data like all comments where "pod" field is fb .** How to extract properly when sqlite json has value **as an array** ?

select json_extract(data,'$."json"')  from datatable ; gives me entire thing . Then I do 
select json_extract(data,'$."json"[0]') but i dont want to do it manually . i want to iterate .

kindly suggest some source where i can study and work on it .
**MY JSON**

```
{
    "ALL": [{
            "comments": "your site is awesome",
            "pod": "passcode",
            "originalDirectory": "case1"
        },
        {
            "comments": "your channel is good",
            "data": ["youTube"],
            "pod": "library"
        },
        {
            "comments": "you like everything",
            "data": ["facebook"],
            "pod": "fb"
        },
        {
            "data": ["twitter"],
            "pod": "tw",
            "ALL": [{
                "data": [{
                    "codeLevel": "3"
                }],
                "pod": "mo",
                "pod2": "p"
            }]
        }
    ]
}



create table datatable ( path string , data json1 );
insert into datatable values("1" , json('<abovejson in a single line>'));
```

Comment: put this json_extract(data,'$."json"[0]')  in a loop

Comment: can you please guide how . Any link to documentation will really help

Comment: Column types of `string` and `json1`? You should read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html very carefully.

Comment: And what you're looking for is [`json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_each_and_json_tree_table_valued_functions).

Comment: @Shawn . can you please share an example . I am unable to understand documentation for this .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Simple List

Where your JSON represents a "simple" list of comments, you want something like:

```
select key, value 
  from datatable, json_each( datatable.data, '$.ALL' )
 where json_extract( value, '$.pod' ) = 'fb' ;
```

which, using your sample data, returns:

```
2|{"comments":"you like everything","data":["facebook"],"pod":"fb"}
```

The use of `json_each()` returns a row for every element of the input JSON (`datatable.data`), starting at the path `$.ALL` (where `$` is the top-level, and `ALL` is the name of your array: the path can be omitted if the top-level of the JSON object is required). In your case, this returns one row for each comment entry.

The fields of this row are documented at [4.13. The json_each() and json_tree() table-valued functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_each_and_json_tree_table_valued_functions) in the SQLite documentation: the two we're interested in are `key` (very roughly, the "row number") and `value` (the JSON for the current element). The latter will contain elements called `comment` and `pod`, etc..

Because we are only interested in elements where `pod` is equal to `fb`, we add a `where` clause, using `json_extract()` to get at `pod` (where `$.pod` is relative to `value` returned by the `json_each` function).

### Nested List

If your JSON contains nested elements (something I didn't notice at first), then you need to use the `json_tree()` function instead of `json_each()`. Whereas the latter will only iterate over the immediate children of the node specified, `json_tree()` will descend recursively through *all* children from the node specified.

To give us some data to work with, I have augmented your test data with an extra element:

```
create table datatable ( path string , data json1 );
insert into datatable values("1" , json('
    {
        "ALL": [{
                "comments": "your site is awesome",
                "pod": "passcode",
                "originalDirectory": "case1"
            },
            {
                "comments": "your channel is good",
                "data": ["youTube"],
                "pod": "library"
            },
            {
                "comments": "you like everything",
                "data": ["facebook"],
                "pod": "fb"
            },
            {
                "data": ["twitter"],
                "pod": "tw",
                "ALL": [{
                    "data": [{
                        "codeLevel": "3"
                    }],
                    "pod": "mo",
                    "pod2": "p"
                },
                {
                    "comments": "inserted by TripeHound",
                    "data": ["facebook"],
                    "pod": "fb"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
'));
```

If we were to simply switch to using `json_each()`, then we see that a simple query (with no `where` clause) will return *all* elements of the source JSON:

```
select key, value 
  from datatable, json_tree( datatable.data, '$.ALL' ) limit 10 ;

ALL|[{"comments":"your site is awesome","pod":"passcode","originalDirectory":"case1"},{"comments":"your channel is good","data":["youTube"],"pod":"library"},{"comments":"you like everything","data":["facebook"],"pod":"fb"},{"data":["twitter"],"pod":"tw","ALL":[{"data":[{"codeLevel":"3"}],"pod":"mo","pod2":"p"},{"comments":"inserted by TripeHound","data":["facebook"],"pod":"fb"}]}]
0|{"comments":"your site is awesome","pod":"passcode","originalDirectory":"case1"}
comments|your site is awesome
pod|passcode
originalDirectory|case1
1|{"comments":"your channel is good","data":["youTube"],"pod":"library"}
comments|your channel is good
data|["youTube"]
0|youTube
pod|library
```

Because JSON objects are mixed in with simple values, we can no longer simply add `where json_extract( value, '$.pod' ) = 'fb'` because this produces errors when `value` does not represent an object. The simplest way around this is to look at the `type` values returned by `json_each()`/`json_tree()`: these will be the string `object` if the row represents a JSON object (see above documentation for other values).

Adding this to the `where` clause (and relying on "short-circuit evaluation" to prevent `json_extract()` being called on non-object rows), we get:

```
select key, value
  from datatable, json_tree( datatable.data, '$.ALL' )
 where type = 'object'
   and json_extract( value, '$.pod' ) = 'fb' ;
```

which returns:

```
2|{"comments":"you like everything","data":["facebook"],"pod":"fb"}
1|{"comments":"inserted by TripeHound","data":["facebook"],"pod":"fb"}
```

If desired, we could use `json_extract()` to break apart the returned objects:

```
.mode column
.headers on
.width 30 15 5
select json_extract( value, '$.comments' ) as Comments,
       json_extract( value, '$.data' ) as Data,
       json_extract( value, '$.pod' ) as POD
  from datatable, json_tree( datatable.data, '$.ALL' )
 where type = 'object'
   and json_extract( value, '$.pod' ) = 'fb' ;

Comments                        Data             POD
------------------------------  ---------------  -----
you like everything             ["facebook"]     fb
inserted by TripeHound          ["facebook"]     fb
```

**Note**: If your structure contained other objects, of different formats, it may not be sufficient to simply select for `type = 'object'`: you may have to devise a more subtle filtering process.

Comment: Thanks sir :) This is ok for first level . How will we go inside the jsons which are at second level ie if you see  "data": ["twitter"], it has another "ALL"  . this query will become complicated . Any suggestion

Comment: Possibly `json_tree` will help... it is similar to `json_each` but (IIRC: I'm away from my computer) it descends down nested layers.

Comment: @MAG I've added a way of using `json_tree()` to (hopefully) do what you want...